# Is there a way to hide my facebook posts to an open facebook group from appearing on my timeline?

Tags: facebook

First of all I must apologise that this question is not actually coding related. I am having a  bit of a 'tish' with my partner as she wants to be able to post to open Facebook groups without the activity appearing in her timeline and her friend's seeing it. I'm saying it cannot be done and to make a new profile and deal with it. She just gets angrier and as I am an IT guy I am supposed to have a solution for everything.

Can someone help me settle this stoush? If you can actually accomplish hiding activity on a timeline that is coming from posting into an open group that would be awesome too! Because I've searched Google and it looks quite unlikely.

Also those of you that object to my posting, please let me know of a more appropriate place and I'll gladly put it up there instead.

Cheers

Comment: maybe post to SuperUser ? not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you post anything anywhere (except a status), its not "posted on timeline". Rather, facebook "share that story on the wall".

Now, privacy of that post is limited to the **group only**. So , no one except the group members can see that post. That story (whatever it is) is shared on the wall of the group members only. So your friends cannot see that story! I'm not sure how you said- *activity appearing in her timeline and her friend's seeing it* – as far as I know, it's not possible.

Also, you can always see the privacy setting of a post while posting itself. For eg:

*Posting on own timeline-*

[image]

*Posting on an open group timeline-*

[image]

See the privacy setting in yellow mark. For a group, it's not editable and limited to a group only!

so, for an open group if a user search for the group and wants to see the activity, then only he can see who's posting what. And that thing can be controlled only if the group is **secret**. [ref](https://www.facebook.com/help/220336891328465)

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty sure it can work on closed groups but open groups there is no control.